# how to do error handling in react js functional components

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-functional-component

```
  {    props.history.map((element,index)=>{
```

return( <>

```
 <Historyy temp={element.main.temp} imgvalue3={imgvalue3} imageUrl={element.weather[0].icon} mintemperature={element.main.temp_min} maxtemperature={element.main.temp_max} weather={element.weather[0].description} wind={element.wind.speed} humidity={element.main.humidity}  time={index + 1}/>
```

</>
)
})                    }

//this is the code i want to do that whenever my map function get a null value or undefined value i can simply show a other message like data not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a possible sollution, ternary operator. if history is null or undefined show your the `h1` tag else show the history component.

```
{props.history ? props.history.map((element,index)=>{
return(<> 
 <Historyy temp={element.main.temp} imgvalue3={imgvalue3} imageUrl={element.weather[0].icon} mintemperature={element.main.temp_min} maxtemperature={element.main.temp_max} weather={element.weather[0].description} wind={element.wind.speed} humidity={element.main.humidity}  time={index + 1}/>
</> ) }) : <h1>an error has occured</h1> }
```